# Arrows in superscripts

Tags: arrows, superscripts

I have something like this:

```
\int\limits _{\left[a,c\right]}f
```

I would like to add the arrow over the [a,b] to emphasize the directionality, but when I try to use:

```
\int\limits _{\overrightarrow{\left[a,c\right]}}f
```

it seems that arrow prevents the upper symbol to look small. I have tried many options but none look good... Many thanks for helping.

Radek

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It will look better, if you use the `\[...\]` style for this integral or `\displaystyle\int\limits_{...}`, however, this will enlarge your equation of course

Comment: Remove `\left` and `\right` to begin with.

Comment: Are you doing `\usepackage{amsmath}`? If not, do.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a macro `\overrightsmallarrow` that “demotes” the arrow to be in the smaller style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\rightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\int\limits_{\overrightarrow{[a,c]}}f
\int\limits_{\overrightsmallarrow{[a,c]}}f
\int\limits_{\overrightsmallarrow{\![a,c]\!}}f
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I added a possible improvement with `\!` for avoiding clash of symbols.

Note that `\left` and `\right` do nothing here and it's not recommended to use them for every pair of delimiters. Add them only if you really need to.

Answer (score 2):

Well-placed `\scripstyle` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
You have 
\[
\int\limits _{\overrightarrow{\left[a,c\right]}}f
\]
You want to
\[
\int\limits _{\overrightarrow{\scriptstyle\left[a,c\right]}}f
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see no difference whatsoever

Comment: @egreg Without `\scripstyle` the interval was as if in the `\textstyle`.

Comment: Sorry, no. It is in script style anyway.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, not in my picture. (OP wants the interval in script style).

Comment: I used `amsmath`, of course.