# Small overleftrightarrow

Tags: math-mode

I am looking for a way to reduce the size of `\overleftrightarrow` (or change it for a similar function), as it seems HUGE compared to `\vec` or `\hat`.
How could I change the function `\te` on the minimum example to obtain something more consistent with the other functions?
Thanks in lot :)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\te}[1] {\overleftrightarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}
The following tensor $\te{A}$ has a huge arrow compared to $\vec{A}$ or $\hat{A}$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248297/4427 (here I put all three “small” versions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overleftrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\leftrightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\rightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overleftsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\leftarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\te}[1]{\overleftrightsmallarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\overleftrightarrow{A}\te{A}\hat{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That do is a very nice peace of code for one little thingy :-p Many thanks indeed (also for such a fast reply).