# how to write under leftright arrow

Tags: arrows

I have question please about writing under arrows

I know `$\overleftarrow{A}$` draw a directed arrow to the left, similarly `$\overrightarrow{A}$` draws a directed arrow to the right, but I can't find a command like `$\overarrow{A}$` to draw left-right arrow.

Anyone can help me in this!

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265841/4427 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any extra package:
`$\stackrel{A}{\leftrightarrow}$`

With amsmath:
`$\underleftrightarrow{A}$`

Comment: This works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

This is for test $\xleftrightarrow{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need A be below the arrow, please.

Comment: `$\xleftrightarrow[B]{}$` ...

Answer (score 2):

There is also a useless package called `halloweenmath` to write `underleftright` arrow. Here there is a table where you can see that the lenght of the arrow is the same of the character.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
Your desidered code: $\underscriptleftrightarrow{A}$.

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
\toprule
$\overscriptleftarrow{A}$      & $\underscriptleftarrow{A}$      \\ \midrule
$\overscriptleftrightarrow{A}$ & $\underscriptleftrightarrow{A}$ \\ \midrule
$\overscriptrightarrow{A}$     & $\underscriptrightarrow{A}$     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```