# Change arrow tip of \overleftarrow-Command

Tags: arrows, amssymb

I defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\pfeil}[2]{[\overleftarrow{#1,#2}]}
```

to visualize the arrows used in the field of graph theory.

[image]

As you can see, the tip of the arrow touches the numbers. Is there any way to change the tip style and the size? For example the 'stealth' tip from the Tikz arrow tip library would be a better choice for my needs. Because the standard tip seems to be too height when used it text mode. See this example (with the command from egreg's answer):

[image]

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248297/4427 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248297/4427

The second row, with `\badpfeil` is just for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overleftsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\leftarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\pfeil}[2]{[\overleftsmallarrow{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}
\newcommand{\badpfeil}[2]{[\overleftarrow{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}


\begin{document}

\[
\pfeil{1}{7}\quad\pfeil{2}{8}\quad\pfeil{8}{3}
\]

\[
\badpfeil{1}{7}\quad\badpfeil{2}{8}\quad\badpfeil{8}{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a different and smaller arrow tip taken from `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathabx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5>    mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11>  mathb10
  <11->     mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\blacktriangleleft}{2}{mathb}{"9E}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overleftsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\smallleftarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern0.4pt}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\smallleftarrowfill@}{%
  \arrowfill@\blacktriangleleft\relbar\relbar
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\pfeil}[2]{[\overleftsmallarrow{#1,#2}]}


\begin{document}

Space between a deep line and a digit:
\the\dimexpr\baselineskip-\fontchardp\font`y-\fontcharht\font`8\relax

Space between a deep line and \verb|\pfeil|
\sbox0{$\pfeil{2}{8}$}
\the\dimexpr\baselineskip-\fontchardp\font`y-\ht0\relax

\[
\pfeil{1}{7}\quad\pfeil{2}{8}\quad\pfeil{8}{3}
\]

yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy
yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy
yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy $\pfeil{2}{8}$ yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy
yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy yyyyyy yyyyy

\end{document}
```

The computation shows that the interline space will not be increased; the arrow tip will almost touch a deep letter, but the probability of this happening is not so high. You might decrease the (already small) kerning to make the touching less evident.

[image]

Comment: @JohnnyDrama I added a new version

Comment: It’s hardly the case to remark that the first version (with CM arrowtips) of the smaller arrows is also made available by the `halloweenmath` package (it’s not a joke, it does exist!).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `old-arrows` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, old-arrows}
\newcommand{\pfeil}[2]{[\overleftarrow{#1,#2}]}

\begin{document} %

\[ \pfeil{1}{7}\enspace\pfeil{2}{8}\enspace\pfeil{8}{3} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]