# Reversed arrow tips for \overleftarrow and \overrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

The post [Change arrow tip of \overleftarrow-Command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426366/change-arrow-tip-of-overleftarrow-command) tells me how to change the size of the tips of arrows generated with `\overleftarrow` and `\overrightarrow`. But how can I get a different tip all together?

Ideally, I would like a reversed arrow tip (like `--<` but not dashed) or small vertical lines for the tip of arrows on top of a letter based on `\overleftarrow` and `\overrightarrow`.

Comment: As for vertical lines as arrow tips, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457887/47927

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use the code of [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506063/47927) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426382/47927) to come up with a solution for an inverted arrow. Note that this may look a bit strage if the text underneath is too short (only one letter, for example). Also note that this approach has not been excessively tested for use in superscript or subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,trimclip}

\makeatletter

\def\lefttailfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar{\vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{6pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\leftarrowtail}}}}}
\ams@newcommand{\overlefttail}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\lefttailfill@}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\olefttail}[2]{[\overlefttail{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}

\begin{document}

\[
\olefttail{2}{5}
\]

\[
\overlefttail{abc}
\]

\[
\sum^{\overlefttail{abc}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: same thing for the right "arrow" and one with two tails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,trimclip}

\makeatletter

\def\righttailfill@{\arrowfill@{\vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 6pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}}}}\relbar\relbar}
\ams@newcommand{\overrighttail}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\righttailfill@}}

\def\leftrighttailfill@{\arrowfill@{\vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 6pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}}}}\relbar{\vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{6pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\leftarrowtail}}}}}
\ams@newcommand{\overleftrighttail}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\leftrighttailfill@}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\orighttail}[2]{[\overrighttail{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}

\newcommand{\oleftrighttail}[2]{[\overleftrighttail{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}

\begin{document}

\[
\orighttail{2}{5}
\]

\[
\overrighttail{abc}
\]

\[
\oleftrighttail{2}{5}
\]

\[
\overleftrighttail{abc}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot. And how do you do the \overrighttail{} ?

Comment: sorry for being dense, I am trying to adjust it myself but am getting some strange symbols

Comment: Based on your answer I tried  for the " right " equivalent but it is not correct 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,trimclip}

\makeatletter


\def\righttailfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 3pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}}}
\ams@newcommand{\overrighttail}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\righttailfill@}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\olefttail}[2]{[\overlefttail{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}

\newcommand{\orighttail}[2]{[\overrighttail{\mathstrut#1,#2}]}
\begin{document}


\[
\overrighttail{abc}
\]

\end{document}

Comment: See the edit of my post for a right-pointing (that is, left-tailed) "arrow".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can I bug you for one more: what if I want the inverted arrow tip on both sides ?

Comment: Sure, see the new edit.

Comment: Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 1):

Run with `lualatex` or `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xlongrightreversedarrow[2][]{\ext@arrow 0055{\longrightreversedarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}} 
\def\longrightreversedarrowfill@{\arrowfill@{}{\relbar}{\char"2919}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\xlongrightreversedarrow[y=f(x,v,w)]{x=f(w)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility with `tikz`. The commands `\overrighttail`, `\overlefttail` and `\overleftrighttail` produce the "arrows" using the syntax `\overrighttail{abc}`, etc.

[image]

An optional second argument allows for styling of the arrow, e.g.,

```
\overleftrighttail[red, semithick, densely dotted, line cap=round]{abc}
```

as seen above. The arrow shape can be changed by replacing `to` in the tikzset with whatever shape you want:

```
\tikzset{tail/.tip={Stealth[reversed, length=4pt]}}
```

[image]

To use as a limit in a `\sum`, see [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659919/125871).

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{tail/.tip={to[reversed, length=1.5pt]}}

\newcommand{\overrighttail}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=0pt](a){$#2$};
    \draw[tail-, #1]([shift={(1pt,2pt)}]a.north west)--([shift={(-1pt,2pt)}]a.north east);}}
\newcommand{\overlefttail}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=0pt](a){$#2$};
    \draw[-tail, #1]([shift={(1pt,2pt)}]a.north west)--([shift={(-1pt,2pt)}]a.north east);}}
\newcommand{\overleftrighttail}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=0pt](a){$#2$};
    \draw[tail-tail, #1]([shift={(1pt,2pt)}]a.north west)--([shift={(-1pt,2pt)}]a.north east);}}

\begin{document}
\[
\overrighttail{abc}\;\overlefttail{abc}\;\overleftrighttail{abc}\;
\overleftrighttail[red, semithick, densely dotted, line cap=round]{abc}
\]
\end{document}
```