# Help: special overhead arrows disformed when in the limit of \sum

Tags: amsmath, arrows

Using the code from [Reversed arrow tips for \overleftarrow and \overrightarrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650613/273857) I could create special arrows on top of letters. However, when using these symbols below a sum the arrows get all messed up (see the examples below). Can you help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,trimclip}

\makeatletter

\def\righttailfill@{\arrowfill@{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 6pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}}\relbar\relbar}
\ams@newcommand{\overrighttail}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\righttailfill@}}

\def\leftrighttailfill@{\arrowfill@{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 6pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}}\relbar{\clipbox{6pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\leftarrowtail}}}
\ams@newcommand{\overleftrighttail}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\leftrighttailfill@}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}



\[
\overrighttail{abc}
\]

\[
\sum _{\overrighttail{abc}}
\]

\[
\overleftrighttail{abc}
\]


\[
\sum _{\overleftrighttail{abc}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I adjusted my [original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650613/273857) a bit to solve this problem. In fact, you need to place `\clipbox{0pt 0pt 6pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}` inside `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`, so that it becomes `\vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 6pt 0pt}{\ensuremath\rightarrowtail}}}`. This will adjust the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a completely different approach using `tikz`. Define new commands `\overrighttail`, `\overlefttail` and `\overleftrighttail` that take an argument as in `\overrighttail{abc}`. These commands place the argument in a `node` and then `draw`s the arrow above. You can adjust spacing by changing the `shift` values.

To use these below (or above) `\sum`, use the additional new command `\limstyle`, which has the usage `\limstyle{\overlefttail{abc}}`. This command uses `\mathclap`, which requires the `mathtools` package.

[image]

An optional second argument allows further styling of the arrow. For example:

`$\overrighttail[red, semithick, densely dotted, line cap=round]{abc}$`

[image]

Note that you can change the `Straight Barb` arrowstyle to many other shapes by changing the `tail/.tip` setting. For example,

```
\tikzset{tail/.tip={to[reversed, length=1.5pt]}}
```

[image]

or `\tikzset{tail/.tip={Latex[reversed, length=4pt]}}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{tail/.tip={Straight Barb[reversed, length=1.5pt]}}

\newcommand{\limstyle}[1]{\mathclap{\scriptsize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\overrighttail}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=0pt](a){$#2$};
    \draw[tail-, #1]([shift={(1pt,2pt)}]a.north west)--([shift={(-1pt,2pt)}]a.north east);}}
\newcommand{\overlefttail}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=0pt](a){$#2$};
    \draw[-tail, #1]([shift={(1pt,2pt)}]a.north west)--([shift={(-1pt,2pt)}]a.north east);}}
\newcommand{\overleftrighttail}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, anchor=base]{\node[inner sep=0pt](a){$#2$};
    \draw[tail-tail, #1]([shift={(1pt,2pt)}]a.north west)--([shift={(-1pt,2pt)}]a.north east);}}

\begin{document}
\[
\overrighttail{abc}\;\overlefttail{abc}\;\overleftrighttail{abc}\;
\sum_{\limstyle{\overrighttail{abc}}}^{\limstyle{\overlefttail{abc}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kaira: It may seem strange, but on this site we typically don't thank other users in comments. The way to show appreciation is to [upvote helpful answers and accept the one that you find _most_ helpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).